# How to make good encapsulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, jasmine

Coming from Java to AngularJS (I'm new to all javascript relating technologies), I'm trying to "translate" my thoughts.
I wrote an object an some tests in Jasmin. Some tests work but one keeps on failing with what seemed to me to be a scope problem.
Here's the code:

```
function Invoice() {

var invoicelines = new LinesHandler();

function LinesHandler() {

    var lines = [];

    function Line() {
        var quantity = 0;
        var description = '';
        var rate = 0;
        var total=0;

        return {
            getQuantity : function() {
                return this.quantity;
            },

            setQuantity : function(quantity) {
                this.quantity = quantity;
                this.refreshTotal();
            },

            getDescription : function() {
                return this.description;
            },

            setDescription : function(description) {
                this.description = description;
            },

            getRate : function() {
                return this.rate;
            },

            setRate : function(rate) {
                this.rate = rate;
                this.refreshTotal();
            },

            getTotal : function() {
                return this.total;
            },

            refreshTotal : function() {
                this.total = this.quantity * this.rate;
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        getLines : function () {
            return lines;
        },

        addLine : function(line) {
            lines.push(line);
        },

        removeLine : function() {},

        editLine : function() {},

        createNewLine : function() {
            return new Line();
        },

        getCount : function() {
            return lines.length;
        },

        getLine : function(i) {
            return lines[i];
        }
    }
}
return {
    createNewLine : function() {return invoicelines.createNewLine();},
    getLinesCount : function() {return invoicelines.getCount();},
    addLine : function(line) {invoicelines.addLine(line);},
    getLines : function() {return invoiceLines;},
    getLinesTotal : function() {
        var total = 0;
        for (line in invoiceLines) {
            total += line.getTotal;
        };
        return total;
    },
    getTaxesTotal: function() {}
};
```

}

And here's the test that fails

```
it('Calculates invoice\'s total while adding lines', function() {
        var invoice = scope.invoice;

        for(var i = 1, j=10; i < 4; i++, j += 10){
            var line = invoice.createNewLine();
            line.setQuantity(j);
            line.setRate(j);
            invoice.addLine(line);
        }

        expect(invoice.getLinesTotal()).toBe(1400);
    });
```

I tried to acces the invoiceLines directly like in other function, I tried with this.invoiceLines, I tried the function getLines(), but the problem is the same I keep getting in firebug something like:

```
ReferenceError: invoiceLines is not defined
```

I dont't really understand the problem. Why do other functions are able to see the private member but not the getLinesTotal function? or the for loop?

Thanks in advance.

PS: don't hesitate to critic the code, I'm sure that it's not the best way to code in Javascript

Comment: I think that you have a typo there. You call your object `invoicelines` but in your function you refer to it as `invoiceLines`

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that :)
Between many other problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your title (how to make good encapsulation in JavaScript), here's a better general pattern to use when structuring your object oriented JavaScript:

```
// Wrap a "class" module in an immediately invoked function expression.
var Parent = (function() {

  // Use a function declaration to create the class's constructor function.
  function Parent(param) {

    // Initialize instance properties from constructor args.
    this.param = param;

    // Initialize any other instance properties we need.
    this.initVar = "foo";
  }

  // Add instance methods to the class's prototype. These will not exist directly on the instance.
  // Instead, JS will look at the instances's prototype to find the value.
  // If you try to access a method (or property) that is not defined on this class prototype,
  // JS will keep looking up the prototype chain. The order here would go:
  //   instance -> instance.[[prototype]] (AKA Parent.prototype) -> Object.prototype -> null
  Parent.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    console.log("Cheese it!");
  };

  // Here we just make a simple method that logs an instance property to the console.
  Parent.prototype.someParentMethod = function() {
    console.log(this.param);
  };

  // Return our now-defined class
  return Parent;

// Immediately invoke the wrapping function expression, returning the Parent class.
}());

// Now lets make a class that inherits from Parent.
var Child = (function() {

  // Make the child constructor
  function Child() {
    // If we want we can call the Parent constructor, passing our Child instance as `this`
    Parent.call(this, "someParam");

    // Do any other child instance initialization
  }

  // Set the Child prototype to a new instance of Parent. For child, the prototype chain will look like:
  //   instance -> instance.[[prototype]] (AKA Child.prototype) -> instance.[[prototype]].[[prototype]] (AKA Parent.prototype) -> Object.prototype -> null
  Child.prototype = new Parent();

  // Point the constructor property to the Child constructor (currently points to Parent)
  Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

  // Override a parent method
  Child.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    console.log("Kill all humans!");
  };

  // Add a method to the Child prototype
  Child.prototype.someChildMethod = function() {
    console.log("Here be dragons");
  };

  return Child;
}());

var myParent = new Parent("foobar");
var myChild  = new Child();
myParent.someMethod();        // => "Cheese it!"
myChild.someMethod();         // => "Kill all humans!"
myParent.someParentMethod(); // => "foobar"
myChild.someParentMethod();  // => "someParam"
myChild.someChildMethod();    // => "Here be dragons"
myParent.someChildMethod();   // => TypeError: Object #<Parent> has no method 'someChildMethod'
```

I know this may not directly answer your question. However, it's a demonstration of creating well encapsulated "classes" with inheritance. The prototype system may take a bit to grok - I've tried to make the comments as clear as possible. The idea is that by attaching methods to the prototype, they are only defined once and therefore take up much less memory. If the method does not exist on the instance itself, it will look up its prototype chain to see if it's defined anywhere, until the prototype chain eventually gets to `null`. Also, by manipulating class prototypes, we can achieve multiple inheritance through composition.

Hopefully that helps a bit. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really what I need. code Javascript in javascript and not in Java

Comment: No problem, it takes a bit to orient yourself to prototypal inheritance coming from a classical inheritance language. Once you've made a few well designed modules, these patterns will become second nature to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cant create an Instance of `LinesHandler` before you define it.
2. Remove the "var" from defining `invoicelines` to make it global (similar to `static` in java)
3. The default return of "new LinesHandler" is `this`, you should not overwrite `return`.
4. The function `Line` is private, define it like `this.line = function(){}`

Comment: I can't make the invocielines global, I want it to be accessed only by the invoice object